# How to dynamic change http.authorizeRequests rules?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I work on content management system, that has antMatchers like the following:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/auth/test1").hasAuthority("test1")
         .antMatchers("/auth/test1").hasAuthority("test2")
         .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

The server start and the rule works.But I need to add new rules like:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/auth/test3").hasAuthority("test3")
         .antMatchers("/auth/test4").hasAuthority("test4")
```

or I need to remove the rule of "test1",just keep 'test2' like :

```
http.authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/auth/test1").hasAuthority("test1")
```

What can I do to meet the above requirements without restarting the server?

Thank you ;)

In SpringSecurity, I noticed if authorization is done by `AccessDecisionVoter#vote` according to the `AccessDecisionManager`, and the attributes value is derived from `Collection< ConfigAttribute>  attributes = this.obtainSecurityMetadataSource().getAttributes(object);`Do I need to rebuild the classes for the relevant functionality and rewrite the relevant methods? If I do that, I lose the point of using the SpringSecurity framework and hope someone can tell me about the solution, thanks.

Comment: Why are you complicate the thinks ? Usually you have to declare this configuration as static one. As I know it won’t change in a dynamic way, because it is already compiled.